# How to access Visualforce JS methods and variables from a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

There are many lightning components are embedded in a Visualforce page.
I've setup many global variables and JS functions to share the state with lightning components.
However, it seems no way that a lightning component could access any global variable or JS method from it's parent contaniner(VF page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Communicating between Lightning Components and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html) article that you may have seen explains:

> Different Origins. Visualforce pages and Lightning Components are
>   served from different domains. For example, if you are using a
>   developer edition:
>
> - Lightning Components are loaded from a domain that looks like this:
>     **yourdomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com**
> - Visualforce pages are loaded
>     from a domain that looks like this:
>     **yourdomain-dev-ed–c.na35.visual.force.com**
>
> The browser’s same-origin policy prevents a page from accessing
>   content or code in another page loaded from a different origin
>   (protocol + port + host).
>
> In our case, that means that a Visualforce page can’t use the parent
>   window reference to access content or execute code in the Lightning
>   Component wrapper. Similarly, the Lightning component can’t use the
>   iframe’s contentWindow reference to access content or execute code in
>   the Visualforce page it wraps.
>
> These restrictions are enforced for very good reasons. But
>   fortunately, there is also an API (otherWindow.postMessage()) that
>   provides a secure approach (when used properly) to exchange messages
>   between different window objects with content loaded from different
>   origins.

So best to think of these as two separate environments and to not attempt to build much logic that spans both.

However, when you have to, you can pass complex objects between the two via the `postMessage` mechanism where the message can be:

> Data to be sent to the other window. The data is serialized using the
>   [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm). This means you can pass a broad variety of
>   data objects safely to the destination window without having to
>   serialize them yourself.

Comment: Hi @Keith However, the case I have is to have a Visualforce page as the parent container which will dynamically create lightning components. Our customers will direct access the vfp. I didn't see any iframe for the included lightning apps in the vfp. Will that still face the same origin issue?

Comment: @newBike I'm not too clear about your mention of iframe here, but FYI [lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm) "provides the message() method".

Comment: So far. It seems to me each Salesforce Lightning component is working in a sanitized sandbox. there's no way to access any JS function or variable outside from the component itself.

Comment: @newBike Yes it is a _very_ tied-down environment. Also see [Sharing JavaScript Code Across Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_share_code.htm).